# HERE API - HelloMap example not running with 4.5.0 - OPTIONS does not support writing etc

Tags: android, here-api

I started exploring HERE API for map related actions on Android. I started with the HelloMap example given on GitHub: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/android/HelloMap

However, after inserting my key_id and key_secret and after adding the 4.5.0 aar into the libs folder, I cannot execute the example in my emulator.

In my run log, I see several exceptions/problems:

```
E/HttpClient: HttpClient::HttpTask::run exception: java.net.ProtocolException: OPTIONS does not support writing
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: OPTIONS does not support writing
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:327)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:123)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:257)
...
D/NetworkAndroid: 09:37:26.432 [DEBUG] NetworkAndroid - CompleteRequest, request_id=1,  uploaded_bytes=37,  downloaded_bytes=0, url=https://account.api.here.com, status=-1
I/OlpClientSettingsFactory: 09:37:26.432 [INFO] OlpClientSettingsFactory - PrewarmConnection: completed for url='https://account.api.here.com', status='-1 java.net.ProtocolException: OPTIONS does not support writing'
E/HttpClient: HttpClient::HttpTask::run exception: java.net.ProtocolException: OPTIONS does not support writing
W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: OPTIONS does not support writing
...
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
        at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
        at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
```

I did a test with HERE some weeks ago with an older version and it worked fine. Unfortunately, I do not have a backup of that project. However, I assume the example given on GitHub should work out of the box. Am I missing any compulsory step?

If you need further info, please tell me. As I said, I added all the details that I was aware of (aar, key_id, key_secret). I tested on Windows and MAC. On both it is not working.

Comment: HI , We also tried run this example with latest aar file and we are successfully able to run the demo. The error logs you pasted is directing towards some client errors  .Could you please try to check your emulator setup by running some other example.

Comment: If you see a blank screen and the app is not crashing, then most likely your credentials are not valid. Note that in your account, the credentials show only APP ID and KEY ID. The needed SECRET KEY is only shown once upon first creation. When you come back later to this credentials page on developer.here.com, you will no longer see the SECRET KEY - and by mistake, maybe you copied APP ID instead? For the _Explore Edition_, the APP ID is not needed.

Comment: @Datasun: Thanks for pointing it out. I am aware of that. I saved my secret key and I checked that the correct ids/keys are used.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Thanks for your feedback. The emulator is running properly for other apps (e.g. the example apps from Android Studio). I also added a new emulator and it fails with the same problem. And as I mentioned in the post, on my MAC it is not working either.

Comment: The error messages from above point to Android. It would be interesting to see what exact error you get on a Mac. There are some min req, are you sure you have met all? E.g. if I am not wrong, Mac OS Catalina is required. Also, it's a bit unclear if you experience a crash or just something else. And one more idea, if you believe that this is caused by a new version, just try the example with an older artifact. They are still available.

Comment: @Datasun Sorry for the late answer. I was looking for old versions but could not find them. Do you have a link available?

Comment: You can select the documentation for older versions from developer.here.com, but to get the artifacts, you would probably need to contact the HERE support, if I am not wrong.